# How to update premake so I can compile a project?

Tags: linux, fedora, premake

I'm trying to build the library Box2D on a new computer running Fedora 17. When I try to build Box2D, I get the error

```
premake4.lua:26: attempt to call global 'vpaths' (a nil value)
```

Some googling suggests that I need to use a newer version of premake. I went to the [premake website](http://industriousone.com/premake/download) to try just downloading an executable (the 4.4 beta version for linux), but running the version they have on their site gives me this error instead:

```
/home/alex/Downloads/premake4: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Whats the proper way to get the proper version and run it?

Answer (score 3):

Grab the source code package available on the download page and build it for your system?

```
$ cd premake-4.4-beta4/build/gmake.unix
$ make
$ cd ../../bin/release
$ ./premake4 --version
premake4 (Premake Build Script Generator) 4.4-beta4
```